# Someone please explain how I'm writing to EXT4 from Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, multi-boot, ntfs, ext4

I'm dual booting Debian amd-64 Wheezy 7.5 and Windows 8.1

I have 6 drives and I am 100% positive that four of the drives are formatted Ext4 (Formatted in Linux)

How on earth is it that when I'm in Windows I can casually read the drives and write to the drives without having installed any special software whatsoever.

I've now switched back and forth between the two operating systems many, many times to make sure I'm not going crazy.

No, they are not FAT32.
No, they are NTFS.

This is a pretty fresh 8.1 installation and again, I have not installed any third-party software.

### Edit:

Added images

[image: img1]

[image: diskmgmt.msc]

Comment: What's displayed in the drive's properties dialog? Did you share it though any network drive?

Comment: Drive properities reveal the ext4 as ext3 (three). no big deal. After I had copied over 2TB to two (2) drives (ext4) I switched over to Debian and made one of the available as a samba share.

Comment: I am not 'installing' programs on any of the ext4 drives. simply copying over 3TB of data files onto each.

Comment: Please post a screenshot of diskmgmt.msc as well as a screenshot of an ext4 drive if possible

Comment: screenshots coming right up.

Comment: all in all, what prompted this whole thing is the NIGHTMARE i have been going through with ReFS. It may be great but it's a long way from being a file system out there as it has no support, not even by Microsoft terminals and 99% of software out there (partitioning) have no idea what it is.

Comment: I have numbers of more drives to backup, format to either ntfs or ext4 and then copy all data back onto... here in these two pics you will see my progress.  20+ drives total to have to tend to...

Comment: [link: http://oi58.tinypic.com/1pfr7r.jpg](http://oi58.tinypic.com/1pfr7r.jpg)

[link: http://oi60.tinypic.com/2mo1sn7.jpg](http://oi60.tinypic.com/2mo1sn7.jpg)

Comment: Note: you should edit the question and add images, not provided them in a comment

Comment: Did you make sure that there's no ext driver being installed in Windows? And are those EXT4 drives directly connect to your computer or shared through network?

Comment: Which four of the drives are supposed to be ext4? Could you give the drive letters?

Comment: All drives internally attached to motherboard. Thanks for the edit-info and fix. I appreciate it. At the time of the snapshot only one drive was ext4 (displayed in windows and ext3). Titled ext4beta i:\ -- as you can see after I'm wiping out all ReFS and copying the data onto newly formatted NTFS drives. When I had booted up prior to this snapshot and maybe a few hours before I had begun with four (4) ext4 drives. In the end, I am going to be safe and eliminate all ReFS drives, copying the data onto NTFS. It is far, far, far too soon to bring ReFS into linux as it goes entirely unrecognized.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is if check-marked some windows-add feature, under programs. But otherwise the windows OS hardly even has any software at all on it. That fastcopy is portable, paint is paint, vnc is portable, firefox is portable.

Comment: May I ask what issues are you encountering with refs? I'm considering using it for 2 equal wd black drives I have, and copy my important stuff there. I don't dual boot.

Answer (score -1):

You can't write to/read from an EXT4-formatted partition in windows without special software, because Windows can only read NTFS, FAT32 and a few others.

Comment: No, it can, but needs something to be downloaded to it.

Comment: But I am. I literally am copy a ton of data from other drive to my ext4 drives without any problems, without having installed anything to make that happen, and I'm losing sleep not understanding how this is possible.

It's a clean Windows 8.1 installation and if you saw the programs and features list you'd realize nothing 3rd party has been added.

At present I have 6 drives; 4 of which are ext4. Ext4 born in Debian amd-64 7.5. 1 is ReFS, 1 is NTFS. I keep rebooting and booting in from linux to make sure I'm not going crazy but everything is working smooth as silk.

Comment: I now shared all ext4 volumes and can read/write to the drives from the general windows share on another Windows 8.1 based laptop. This is killing me because I had formatted other drives with the MISERABLE ReFS [fs] which neither debian nor centOS/fedora could even mount.

Comment: TimoS, Windows can read/write to ext2/ext3 with the most simple, free standalone software you can imagine. that isn't any issue. but in this case, there's no software, it's ext4 and it's working as if I've no fs compatibility issue had ever existed in the first place.